# How can I do curved mirroring in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, reflection

how can I do this result speaking by reflection?
If I use the simple vertical reflection I lose left and right sides..  But in this image the mirroring starts from the bracelet (the mirroring is "curved") instead from an imaginary line.. how can I do this? 
Tnx

[bracelet](http://www.charmsaddict.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/nomination-mothers-day-bracelets.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to  GD.SE. im afraid we need more info, there is no simple answer to your question. Can it be done? Nearly anything can but are you willing to invest the time to do so is another issue. I would call this a reflection instead.

Comment: Joojaa, sorry If I used a wrong term but I'm not native English speaker!

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you would make this effect when taking a photograph of the product.

For something this complex I would draw a path around each bracelet bracket. My way of doing this would be very time consuming. **You might be able to just draw a path around the last bracelet and just move that down and then draw gradients to cover the flower design things** (Instead of just copying just one bracket).

I would start out but drawing a path around one of the bracelet brackets using the pen tool (p).

[image: draw path around bracelet bracket]

I first lowered the transparency of the layer. I then created a layer mask for the duplicated bracelet bracket to cover up the overlap and lower the transparency of the bottom part of the bracket. I then moved the layer down to start making the reflection.

[image: the reflection]

I then made a new path and used a gradient to cover up the the flower design.

[image: gradient layer]

You would then trace the flower design itself and then reflect that and maybe use the warp tool.

The comparison, I didn't do the flower part but you get the idea.

[image: comparison]

Comment: AndrewH, you have been so clear and helping! I appreciated that u used some pics to show me how to do..! :)   Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Jenny Happy to help, and welcome to GD.SE. If this answer or any other answers end up solving your issue, please remember to mark it as accepted.