# How to warp an image as if it were reflected in a convex surface

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, reflection

I want to make an image look like it is being reflected in a mirrored, convex shape (in this case the visor of a helmet).

What sort of settings and effects would best achieve this?

Comment: Is this question similar to what you're trying to do - [How can I do curved mirroring in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57672/how-can-i-do-curved-mirroring-in-photoshop/57680#57680)

Comment: not really, its more like, imagine an image reflected in the back of a spoon, how would one achieve this sort of effect with warping?

Answer (score 1):

Use Warp in Edit->Transform. Set it to "Bulge" and tweak the settings (you want it positive for convex). Then you can set it to "custom" it will keep your current settings but let you tweak it further by moving the handlels on the corners.

Answer (score -1):

In Photoshop, you could try Filter\Distort\Spherize.

Comment: Would you mind giving a little more explanation to your answer? One-line answers aren't particularly helpful. Generally it's best to give examples or explain how or why your method works/is best to use. Any additional information would be of use here (even a link to a great tutorial showing how to use this function if you don't want to write out an example).